# Jquery Match Value to Array

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays

I have a navigation bar and divs that I want to show when their nav bar link is clicked on. Instead of having the divs be the descendants of the nav bar links, they are separate (I know this probably shouldn't be done). So, I created a data label for each nav bar link that matches the data label of the div that should be shown on click.

So, I want to click the nav link, find the data label (which I've done successfully with Jquery), match that data label against the different divs and display that div (while hiding the others). I think I need to create an array of the divs, then have some Jquery code to create an array and go through it to find the matching data type, then show that div...thanks for your help!

```html
  <div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="main1" data-type="1">Main 1</div>
  <div id="main2" data-type="2">Main 2</div>
  <div id="main3" data-type="3">Main 3</div>
  <div id="main4" data-type="4">Main 4</div>
  <div id="main5" data-type="5">Main 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, hide all the divs on click, then show the one you want:

```
$("#nav ul li").click(function() {
    $("#main div").hide(); //hide others if open
    var type = $("a", this).data("type"); //get the data-type value of the clicked li's a child tag
    $("#main div[data-type='" + type + "']").show(); //show the matching data-type div 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xdsm52c6/

Comment: This is great. Thank you for this simple solution. I was over-thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a tabgroup for the navigation, it'll display at the top of your page and once you click on different tabs it'll display each div. you can configure each div differently and wouldn't have to worry about them displaying on a page together.

Documentation: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Example of a basic tab interface provided by jqueryui.com :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
<p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find code that solves your issue with several performance enhancements (see details inline in comments to the code).

```js
var divs = $('#main [data-type]').hide(); // search divs one time instead of traversing DOM each time link is clicked

$('#nav').on('click', '.navselection', function() { // Bind one event listener to #nav with scope selector instead of having event listener on each link
  var type = this.getAttribute('data-type'); // minimize calls of slow DOM APIs by caching relevant data-type
  $.each(divs, function(index, div) { // iterate array only once and apply relevant function
    $(div)[div.getAttribute('data-type') === type ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navselection" data-type="5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="main1" data-type="1">Main 1</div>
  <div id="main2" data-type="2">Main 2</div>
  <div id="main3" data-type="3">Main 3</div>
  <div id="main4" data-type="4">Main 4</div>
  <div id="main5" data-type="5">Main 5</div>
</div>
```

Also there is a solution without JavaScript at all (using CSS only)

```css
#main > div {
  display: none;
}
#main > div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#main1" class="navselection">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main2" class="navselection">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main3" class="navselection">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main4" class="navselection">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main5" class="navselection">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="main1">Main 1</div>
  <div id="main2">Main 2</div>
  <div id="main3">Main 3</div>
  <div id="main4">Main 4</div>
  <div id="main5">Main 5</div>
</div>
```